# Get an item from a linked list

Tags: delphi, linked-list, pascal

I have this:

```
type
  PList = ^TSome;

  TSome = record
     next :PList;
...

var
  tmp:PList;
...
begin
  tmp := list;
  while tmp^.next <> nil do
    tmp := tmp^.next;
end
```

Is there any way to get an item on the second index?

Like `array[2]`, but since this is not an array it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it's usually done:

```
var
  tmp: PList;
  index: Integer;
begin
  index := 0;
  tmp := list;

  repeat
    tmp := tmp^.next;
    Inc(Index);
  until (tmp = nil) or (index = 2);
end;
```

Comment: exactly the second object is needed

Comment: @fantaghirocco: I would use `while` loop instead of a `repeat` loop, eg: `index := 2; tmp := list; while (tmp <> nil) and (index > 0) do begin tmp := tmp^.next; Dec(Index); end;` Think of what happens if the caller wants the node at index 0; Your `repeat` loop would fail.

Comment: @vpe27339: do you want the *second node in the list*, or the *node at index 2*? Those are different nodes. Indexes start at 0, so the first node is index 0, the second node is index 1, the third node is index 2, and so on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you're right but I've kept the code "simple" only to point the direction. With this in mind is pretty easy to wrap the idea in a function checking bounds and possible errors in my opinion

Comment: @RemyLebeau regarding the indexes, it's obvious what the second object is since there's no index at all. Obtain the first record/pointer with this code does not make sense because it's the pointer the user starts with - and he/her already knows it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  ok, "first" is misleading... it's better reasoning with **root node** - the object the user knows - and **child nodes** - aka the 1st, the 2nd and so on - the "2nd object" being the 2nd child

Comment: @fantaghirocco: It depends on the list implementation. Some people define the root node as the first real data object in the list, where the root can be null. Some people define the root node as not a data node but just a container to hold the real data nodes, and son the root is never null.

Comment: @RemyLebeau so if the root is valid the user does not need the procedure to obtain the very 1st element; if not, the first valid data is the 1st child and the `repeat` loop applies. Only OP knows it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98278/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-fantaghirocco).

Comment: while is correct here, assuming that tmp can be nil, as one would expect

Comment: @DavidH I'm not arguing this but the point related to the code in the question here is the **counter** and the **exit condition** from the loop. The OP doesn't check the object first and my answer applies to that. It seems to me we're overcomplicating simple things... :-s

Comment: It should be simple. But throwing an AV when the list is empty is not good. Loops over linked lists that can be empty are always written with while. That's the idiom.

Answer (score 1):

But this would be sloooow! much slower than arrays.

```
TSome = record
     next :PList;
     ...

     function GetNext(skip: cardinal): TSome;
     property ArrayLike[index: cardinal]: TSome read GetNext; default;
end;

....

{$T+}
function TSome.GetNext(skip: cardinal): TSome;
type PSome = PList;
var candidate: PSome;
begin
  candidate := @Self;
  while skip > 0 do
    candidate := candidate.Next;
    if candidate = nil then raise EBoundsError.Create('out of index');
    Dec(skip);
  end;
  Result := candidate^;
end;

...

var x: TSome;

 x[0] = x.ArrayLike[0] = x;
```

WARNING: since you work with records, not classes - you get a COPY of record not the record itself;

Like in `var x,y: TSome; y := x;` - you do a NEW DATA COPY, not a second pointer to the same data.

This as well as the very issue of list structure would make this kind of access slower, much slower than array.

And

```
var x,y,z: TSome; i: integer;

x.SomeValue := 1;
y.SomeValue := 2;
x.Next := @y;

i := x[1].SomeValue; 
// i == 2 ( making copy of y, then taking a SomeValue from it)

x[1].SomeValue := 10; 
z := x[1];
z.SomeValue := 20;

i := x[1].SomeValue; 
// still i == 2 - we were NOT changing the value in y itself, we were making DATA COPIES of y and changing COPIES
```

Comment: A pointer to `TSome` would be a better result value for `GetNext` and `ArrayLike`.

Comment: @LURD performance-wise - yes, but: 1) topic starter asked for "to get an item" not ptr, and 2: it still would be slow, lists are not for random access